# does DMS replication instance upgrade require restarting rather than resuming cdc replication task

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, database-replication, aws-dms, dms

I have to upgrade the DMS replication instance, and the terraform plan shows that the replication instance for the CDC sync "must be replaced" after the upgrade:

```
  # module.dms_cdc_replication_task.aws_dms_replication_task.replication_task must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "replication_task" {
```

If I replace the replication task does that mean I'm required to "Restart" (rather than "Resume") the task? As in, does the cdc replication pick up from where it left off before the instance reboot/upgrade?

Judging from this documentation page the task will resume from the last place it stopped:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-restart-resume-failed-task

but I'm unsure as the task will be "replaced" by terraform (because I'll be attaching it to a new replication instance)

Comment: So I tried it out and it looks like yes, it required replacing and therefore restarting the cdc stream